# Como permitir que essa função receba apenas números?

Tags: javascript

Bom dia gente, estou estudando JavaScript e gostaria de saber como mandar uma mensagem de erro caso o usuário insira uma string no lugar de um número, tentei fazer um código com esse intuito, ele até detecta se é um numero ou não, mas não manda a mensagem de erro.
Esse é o código que fiz:

```js
    const aprovacao = function(nota){
    nota = Number(nota);
    if(nota !== NaN){ 
        if(nota >= 7){
            console.log("Aprovado.");
        } else{
            console.log("Reprovado.");
        }
    } else{
        console.log("Por favor digite um número.");
    }
    console.log(nota);
}


aprovacao(5);//mostra reprovado
aprovacao(9);//mostra aprovado
aprovacao("oi");//mostra reprovado
```

Comment: Basta usar [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN), exemplo: `nota = Number(nota); if(Number.isNaN(nota)) { console.log("Por favor digite um número."); } else if(nota >= 7) { console.log("Aprovado."); } else { console.log("Por favor digite um número."); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o operador `typeof`. Ele irá avaliar e retornar o tipo da variável.

```js
const aprovacao = function(nota){
  if(typeof nota !== "number"){
    console.log("Por favor digite um número.");
    return; 
  }

  if(nota >= 7){
    console.log("Aprovado.");
  } else{
    console.log("Reprovado.");
  }
}

aprovacao(5);//mostra reprovado
aprovacao(9);//mostra aprovado 
aprovacao("oi");//mostra "Por favor digite um número."
```